# Depreciation on Rental Bikes

Tags: depreciation

Need some help to understand how to calculate depreciation. Here's my situation:

I've been asked to invest an e-bike business.

They buy the bikes in @ wholesale price.

The bikes are rented out on a monthly subscription to customers.

Bikes are sold on the second hand market before they reach 12 months old.

This is to ensure that the fleet of available bikes is always the latest.

If a customer has a bike nearing 12 months old, they will be asked to swap it for a newer model.

As I assess the opportunity I don't know whether to calculate depreciation on the bikes based on

A. wholesale price - what company initially outlays to purchase and bring the asset on to the books.

B. retail market value - what the company could sell the bike for at any given point in time.

The difference between the two starring points makes quite a difference to the P&L.

Can someone help me understand which number is the right one? Thanks!

Comment: This is a purely accounting question and is off-topic on this site. You should talk to a licensed/charted/certified accountant in your jurisdiction (CPA, or whatever they're called locally). They'll explain to you how depreciation works in accounting, how it differs from real life, and how it is being reconciled in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1):

Depreciation is the mechanism to record the expense resulting from the drop in value of an asset over its lifetime. If depreciation were *not* recorded, when an asset was sold the "loss" from the sale would be recorded at the very end of its life, resulting in "lumpy" profits. It should be calculated based on the original cost (not market value) and ideally get the correct "value" of the asset whenever it's removed from the books.

So if a bike cost $1,000 (to the company, not retail), and you expected to sell it for $400 in one year, you would depreciate it at a rate of $50/month (assuming straight-line depreciation; there are other, more complicated methods).

However, as an *investor*, depreciation can be tricky to analyze. There's no rule that says depreciation *has* to be calculated a certain way, and companies have some flexibility to either understate (if they want to look more profitable) or overstate (if they want to reduce taxes) depreciation in various ways. Ideally you would want depreciation to be used to accurately reflect the current value of the company's assets.  Whether it does that or not is hard to determine.

That's one reason why "cash is king" in many valuation models - look at how much cash the company is expected top bring it and use *that* as your investment basis, since non-cash expenses can distort profitability.

Comment: That's actually absolutely incorrect from accounting standpoint, even if makes sense and sounds reasonable.